# Java ArrayList Index

Tags: java, arraylist

```
int[] alist = new int [3];
alist.add("apple");
alist.add("banana");
alist.add("orange");
```

Say that I want to use the second item in the ArrayList. What is the coding in order to get the following output?

output:

banana

Comment: Your code will not compile: alist it an array, but you use it like an List -- this is impossible and alist is of type integer - you are not able to assign Strings to it.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have `ArrayList` all wrong,

- You can't have an integer array and assign a string value.
- You cannot do a `add()` method in an array

Rather do this:

```
List<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
alist.add("apple");
alist.add("banana");
alist.add("orange");

String value = alist.get(1); //returns the 2nd item from list, in this case "banana"
```

Indexing is counted from `0` to `N-1` where `N` is `size()` of list.

Answer (score 20):

Read more about  [Array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add("apple");   
aList.add("banana");   
aList.add("orange");   
String result = alist.get(1);  //this will retrieve banana
```

Note: Index starts from 0 i.e. Zero

- [Resource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

Answer (score 9):

Using an Array:

```
String[] fruits = new String[3]; // make a 3 element array
fruits[0]="apple";
fruits[1]="banana";
fruits[2]="orange";
System.out.println(fruits[1]); // output the second element
```

Using a List

```
ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("banana");
fruits.add("orange");
System.out.println(fruits.get(1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Exactly as arrays in all C-like languages. The indexes start from 0. So, apple is 0, banana is 1, orange is 2 etc.

Answer (score 5):

In order to store Strings in an dynamic array (add-method) you can't define it as an array of integers ( int[3] ). You should declare it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
alist.add("apple"); 
alist.add("banana"); 
alist.add("orange"); 

System.out.println( alist.get(1) );
```

Answer (score 3):

The big difference between primitive arrays & object-based collections (e.g., ArrayList) is that the latter can grow (or shrink) dynamically. Primitive arrays are fixed in size: Once you create them, their size doesn't change (though the contents can).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would write it.

```
String[] fruit = "apple banana orange".split(" ");
System.out.println(fruit[1]);
```

Comment: You are not serious, are you? Why not write your first line as `String[] fruit = "applesbananasorange".replace('s', ' ').split(" ");`? The CPU should be used, if there is already one.