# Index of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

From my AP Computer Science A review book:

> Consider this program segment. You may assume that the `wordList` has been declared as `ArrayList<String>`.
>
> ```
> for(String s : wordList)
>    if(s.length() < 4)
>      System.out.println("SHORT WORD");
> ```
>
> "What is the maximum number of times SHORT WORD can be printed?"

The book says the answer is wordList.size(), but why wouldn't it be wordList.size()-1?
Is the index of an ArrayList different from a regular array? My book says something about it automatically adding one to the index but I may have read that wrong.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the question, really?

Comment: "the answer is wordList.size()" What's the question?

Comment: I'm not sure you're giving enough context for a meaningful answer here.  What's the question?

Comment: I'm assuming this is `java`. ArrayList is zero-based (as are arrays). No difference there.

Comment: Irony here is that there's several questions, about there not being a question.

Comment: so many badges for this question

Comment: Next time search more before you ask. The answer is for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313457/java-arraylist-index

Comment: To provide an answer to this question, one must first provide the question. How zen.

Comment: I am so sorry! I'm extremely nervous because the exam is tomorrow. I updated the question.

Comment: @Mia Ccio: Don't worry. The question does make a lot more sense in it's updated version. Success with your exam!

Comment: Wow you guys really attacked this question... Thank you so much for all the answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The book says the answer is wordList.size(), but why wouldn't it be wordList.size()-1?

It won't and it can't, because the maximum number of times it can be printed, is if all words in `wordList` have lesser than four characters.

I think you might be confusing the number of elements in the `ArrayList` with the valid indices of an `ArrayList`. Arrays and `List`s in Java are zero-based and so run from `0` to `list.size() - 1`. This means the last element is at `list.size() - 1`. Think of it this way. If you have the numbers `0, 1, 2, 3`, how many numbers do you have in total? You have *four* numbers. However if these numbers were shoved into a zero-based array then the first element is at location `0`, the second element is at location `1` and so on until you have the last element at location `3`.

This picture may help you out:

```
Indices:   0   1   2   3
         +---+---+---+---+
Values:  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
         +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: @MiaCcio No problem. Good luck on your exam!

Answer (score 2):

Of course the maximum is wordList.size(), this happens when all wordList's words are short words. Then, wordList from position 0 to position wordList.size() - 1 (both included) are short.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused, if all the words are short, then why would it still be wordList.size()? Wouldn't it be one less than that?

Comment: OH WAIT I'm referring to the indices rather than the actual number of times, aren't I?

Comment: The number of String elements that you have in wordList is wordList.size(). The first position that contains an String in wordList is 0 and the last one is wordList.size() - 1. So, yes you are confusing with the maximum index of the data structure which is wordList.size() - 1. But you should look at the total number of elements which is wordList.size().

Answer (score 1):

The maximum index of an array or ArrayList will be size-1.  This is because the index of a collection is 0 based.  You can think of the index as an offset.

Let's say I have an ArrayList with the following contents:

`["abc"]`

There is `1` element in the array, so its size is `1`.  The index (or offset) of the first element is `0` because it is at the root of the array.  If my array is:

`["abc", "bcd", "cde", "def" ]`

Then you can see that there are 4 entries in the array, so the size is `4`.  The offset to the final element "def" is 3 because you have to take 3 steps forward from the root to get there.  0 steps gives you "abc", 1 step gives "bcd", 2 = "cde" and 3 = "def".  So the `size` is 4 but you can't get the item at the 4th index because 4 steps takes you beyond "def".

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String s : wordList)
   if(s.length() < 4)
     System.out.println("SHORT WORD");
```

basically says "Call the first word in the list s. If this word is less than 4 letters long, print "SHORT WORD" to the console. Now, repeat for the second word and so on until there are no words left."

Therefore, if all of the words in the list were less than 4 letters long, "SHORT WORD" would be printed wordlist.size() times.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> "What is the maximum number of times SHORT WORD can be printed?"

If all items of `wordList` have `length < 4`, then all items will be printed.

So, how many itens does `wordList` have? Simple: `wordList.size()`.

**`ArrayList`'s `size()` method semantic:**

In a `ArrayList` with a total of `3` itens, such as:

```
ArrayList wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordList.add("firstWord");
wordList.add("2ndWrd");
wordList.add("3w");
```

The `size()` is the number of items (like `array.length`). So, in this case, `3`.

But `ArrayList`'s index, as a regular array, is **0-based** (going from `0` to `size()-1`). So:

```
wordList.get(0); // returns "firstWord"
wordList.get(1); // returns "2ndWrd"
wordList.get(2); // returns "3w"
wordList.get(3); // throws an exception (IndexOutOfBoundsException)
```

Thus your confusion.

Comment: I think I got messed up on the actual indices rather than what the question really asked. I put the last index to be processed, not the number of times. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Infinetely many times.
word list is declared as ArrayList, but it can actually be subclass of array list.
Thus you can make array list that returns infinite iterator returning empty strings.

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public String next() {
                    return "";
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }
            };
        }
    };
    for (String s : wordList) {
        if (s.length() < 4) {
            System.out.println("SHORT WORD");
        }
    }
```