# Converting ArrayLists to Arrays (A bit different)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

I know this question is asked a lot of times in Stack Overflow but mine is a bit different.

I understand that `ArrayList` begin at index 1 and `Arrays` begin at index 0. Am I right?

If not then when I convert my `ArrayList` to an Array.

Ex: code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("India");
list.add("Switzerland");
list.add("Italy");
list.add("France");

String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

So if I my first comment was right (If it was. Because on the net I find 3/4 people saying array list begins at 0 at 1/4 saying array list begins at 1. I am a beginner so I have no idea, which is correct?

So if `ArrayList` begin at 1.

So can the Ex: Code be converted to

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("India");
list.add("Switzerland");
list.add("Italy");
list.add("France");

String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()-1]);
```

Pls. do let me know. 
Thanks!

Comment: The change I made in the second code is that:                                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("India");
list.add("Switzerland");
list.add("Italy");
list.add("France");

String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()-**1**]);                   _marked in **bold**_

Comment: This question has no connection to android

Comment: Ok its related to an app I'm making but if you say so. I'll remove that tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()-1])
```

This line of code will produce an array with countries from given list decreased by one last row.

Both `arrays` and `lists` indexing starts with 0 in Java.
Every first element in arrays and lists begin with index equal to **0**.
Every list from JAVA API implements Collection interface and its `size()` method returns exact number of elements in used collection.

Check out this: [Java ArrayList Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313457/java-arraylist-index)

Comment: In a certain app of mine I asked my ArrayList to display the `.size()` property. The number of Strings added were 7. So if you are right shouldn't the size be 6. Yet it showed me `.size()' = 7.

Comment: Pls do understand I am a beginner so pls do help me understand.

Comment: The length of an array with index values 0 through 6 is 7, just like the size of an ArrayList with index values 0 through 6.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Oh! Thanks a lot for explaining it to me!

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE Keep in mind that `index` of `List` is for tracking current element that you work on. And `size` is exact amount of elements inside it.

Comment: @mastah Thanks for letting me know! So is there an index property for `ListArrays`.

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE no it doesn't. I did some research on my own and here is the conclusion: ArrayList implementation keeps data as an array inside itself - so `get(index)`method works like array[index]. If it comes to Lists like LinkedList - it keeps data in inside structure like stack or heap and given index in `get()` is used as loop break when it reaches for next element in used data structure.

Comment: @mastah Thanks mastah I figured it out my app is working fine and thanks for ur reply

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE no problem, for more the amount of elements you get by `size()` is kept as class field in both cases (`ArrayList` and `LinkedList`) - so in future, using `size()` in loops doesn't cause performance reduce.

Comment: @mastah Ok Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList is like normal Arrays starts at index 0.

You can check using this code.

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(list.get(i)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists are zero based for indexing, as are all collections in Java, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, C#, R, C...

Comment: In a certain app of mine I asked my ArrayList to display the .size() property. The number of Strings added were 7. So if you are right shouldn't the size be 6. Yet it showed me `.size()' = 7.                                                                             Then why is this happening.

Comment: The size property is the number of elements not the highest index.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me!